# how to test themethod returns the correct value and set the correct values in another variable?

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, testing

I have a method that as parameters receive a list that has the nodes of a tree and a jagged array that which nodes I want to repace by anothers. The method returns a list with the new hierarchy. However, the original nodes is not lost, is save as a new tree. My method is:

```
public List<Nodes> exchangeNodes(List<Nodes> paramOriginalTree, Nodes[][] param newNodes)
{
    //code
}
```

Well, with unit test I can use a method that call this exchangeNodes and test if the result is the expected result. Somthing like that:

public void exchangeNodesTest()
{
    //1.- Create nodes and populate a list with the tree.
    //2.- Create a jagged array with the exchanges
    //3.- call the method and save the result in a new list
    //4.- I use asserts to test if the result is correct

```
List<Nodes> lstNewTree = exchangeNodes(lstActualTree, exchangedNodes);

assert(lstNewTree.Count = 4);
....


//How I test if the old nodes has the correct hierarchy?
```

}

But how I can test that the original replaced nodes have the correct hierarchy? Because the method only returns the new hierarchy. I would like to avoid the need to return also a jagged arraid for example with a list of the hierarchy of all the replaced nodes only for test purposes.

Thanks.

EDIT: I need to test the original replaced nodes because it will be saved in a database. I am using EF6 and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/), which I recommend. You can create an extension method that will to the job:

```
public static class FluentAssertionsExtensions
{
    public static void ShouldBeEquivalentWithOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable1, IEnumerable<T> enumerable2)
    {
        enumerable1 = enumerable1.ToList(); // to materailize the collection
        enumerable2 = enumerable2.ToList(); // to materailize the collection
        enumerable1.Should().ContainInOrder(enumerable2); 
        enumerable2.Should().ContainInOrder(enumerable1); // to meke sute enumerable2 is not just a subset of enumerbale1
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can create a simple helper that will use a for loop to go through the collection.